# Enum get value by reference c#

Tags: c#

I have an application where I get an id from the user, then `"Voicetrading"+id` matches one of the values in my Enum called SipUsernames. What i want to do is to get the value that matches `"Voicetrading"+id` and return it.
Is there any way by doing it passing reference type like `SipUsernames.&voicetrading.ToString()` ?

Code example:

```
    foreach(var EnumCountry in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SipUsernames)))
       {
           string voicetrading = "Voicetrading"+id;
           if (voicetrading.Equals(EnumCountry.ToString()))
           {
               return SipUsernames.&voicetrading.ToString();                               
           }
       }
```

Ps. I know `SipUsernames.&voicetrading` is something stupid and doesn't work, but i didn't know how to express what i mean in another way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Isn't in your example `SipUsernames.&voicetrading.ToString();  ` going to be just equal `voicetrading` because that is already a string?

Comment: @zaitsman yes they are, that is true, but my intention is to retrieve the value from the Enum

Comment: Your options are to return:  EnumCountry  (returns the enum),   EnumCountry.ToString(), or to return the underlying number of the enum:  (int) EnumCountry